# UICollectionView inside Custom UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make a custom toolbar using a UICollectionView.

I want to subclass UIView and have the collection view as a child subview.

I'm using the standard flow layout and all works well if I add a collection view to a view controller.(see image)

The moment I add the UICollectionview to MY subclasses view it all stops working correctly.
The items appear outside of the view to begin with and I have to scroll down to see them. It seems to be adding a row of blank space before the items begin.

When I call contentSize on the collectionview inside my UIView subclass, it returns -20 for the height for some reason.

Im pointing the the datasource of CollectionView hosted directly in the view controllers view at an instance of my toolbar so I can rule out code differences. I'm thinking that I maybe missing some subtle issue maybe relating to UIView lifecycle events?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)updateConstraints
{

    [super updateConstraints];

    UIView* view = _collectionView;


    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0]];
    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0]];

    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:0]];
    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:0]];
}

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [_collectionView reloadData];
}

+(BOOL)requiresConstraintBasedLayout
{
    return YES;
}


-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        _itemsVisibleAtOnce = 5;


     //   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
          //  layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
            UICollectionView* collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds collectionViewLayout:layout];
            _collectionView = collectionView;


            [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"OSButtonBarCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:REUSUE_OS_TAB_CELL];


            _collectionView.delegate = self;
            _collectionView.dataSource = self;


            _collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
           [self addSubview:_collectionView];

           // [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];

        [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];




       // });

    }

    return self;
}




/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger numItemsHorizontal = [self collectionView:collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:indexPath.section];

    if (_itemsVisibleAtOnce < numItemsHorizontal)
    {
        numItemsHorizontal = _itemsVisibleAtOnce;
    }

    CGFloat itemWidth = collectionView.bounds.size.width / numItemsHorizontal;
    return CGSizeMake(itemWidth, 30);
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0;
}

-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    OSButtonBarItem* button = _buttons[indexPath.row];

    OSButtonBarCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:REUSUE_OS_TAB_CELL forIndexPath:indexPath];
   // cell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    cell.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    cell.indexPath = indexPath;
    cell.titleLabel.text = button.text;
    cell.backgroundColor = button.backgroundColour;
    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _buttons.count;
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions about what might be happening I would be most greatful!

Many thanks
Chris